# Strange OS X desktop animation

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, desktop

I've noticed a strange animation on the desktop of my January 2007 Macbook Pro.  The animation appears sporadically in the lower left-hand corner.  The best way I can describe the animation is "a hard disk being accessed".  The image is a simple cartoon hard disk being read.  The animation appears very briefly.  **Have you seen something like this**?

Cheers!

Comment: It might help if you can post a screen-shot.

Answer (score 3):

All sorts of third party activity monitors add that sort of animation.

Have you looked in LaunchAgents and LaunchDaemons folders in /Library and ~/Library to temporarily remove any you are not SURE you need? Also, it could be something started in Accounts preferences - Login Items.

I have never seen anything since OS 9 days from Apple that popped up animations like that.

Good luck hunting it down!